# How do I recursively find all matching rows in a table?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to wrangle an existing database without resorting to tricks. I need to query within a linking table to find all matching id's recursively.

I've tried a number of nested join queries, but I'm not a SQL expert. I'm a programmer and while I work with simple databases complex queries like this are a struggle for me.

My table looks like this:

```
------------------------
| child_id | parent_ id|
________________________
    2           16
    3           16
    4           16 
    11          10
    12          11
    16          7
    17          10
    18          17
    19          7
    20          19
    21          10
    22          21
    23          22
    24          22
    26          20
```

I only know the top-level `parent id`. I want to find all associated child ID's.

If the `parent ID` was 7, I need to return 16,19,2,3,4,20,26.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL (mariadb).

Comment: I'm afraid I know the answer but you, by any chance, now the maximum depth, number of levels ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: The number of levels probably goes down to about 4 from a practical perspective, but is not theoretically limited.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/

Comment: In case your mariadb version is lower than 10.2, then Common Table Expression is not available, and you may use "CONNECT BY" statement instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** This solution will work in MariaDB 10.2.2 and above.

Try [Common Table Expression](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cte-in-sql/):

```
with recursive cte(child_id, parent_id) as (
    select child_id, parent_id from MyTable
    where parent_id = 7    
       union all 
    select mt.child_id, mt.parent_id from MyTable mt
         inner join cte t on mt.parent_id = t.child_id
)
select * from cte;
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw that possible duplicate. The query above makes some sense to me, but I get a syntax error when I try to execute it.  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'recursive cte(child_id, parent_id) as (
    select child_id, parent_id from man' at line 1

Comment: @DanGray, which one?

Comment: @DanGray Which version of MariaDB are you using? Here's a [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=4ce65d148deeb2c90dc8805cf7f5656f).

Comment: Yes - I'm on 5.7 which does't support recursive queries.

Comment: Upgraded to mariadb 10. Works great now. Thanks you!!

Comment: @DanGray - MySQL does not have CTEs until 8.0.